# How to set up SSL for localhost and virtual hosts with MAMP?

Tags: apache, ssl, mamp

I'm creating this "question" to document how I was able to set up SSL locally, in case I need to do this again in the future. Thought I'd document it here hoping this can be of help to others too, 'cause it's a tricky process.

I'm working on a Mac with High Sierra, MAMP v 4.2.1 and Chrome v 71

Alright, let's roll.

Answer (score 6):

### 1) Create a SSL certificate for localhost

To be able to use HTTPS with `localhost` we actually need two certificates: a **root certificate**, and a **domain certificate** specifically created for the `localhost` domain.

[These nifty scripts](https://github.com/dakshshah96/local-cert-generator) I've found take care of creating both. They're very easy to use—just follow the instructions closely and you'll be good to go. The only thing that is not so clear in the documentation is that, where it says `Then mark the certificate as trusted`, this means you have to click on the certificate in Keychain Access and change the `Trust` option to `Always`.

([Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec) you can find a more elaborate explanation of what those scripts actually do)

If everything worked for you, you should now have two files `server.crt` and `server.key`. I've created a `ssl` folder in `/Applications/MAMP` and moved the files in it; but you can put them wherever you think is best.

Let's forget about the files now and proceed to some Apache configuration.

### 2) Configure MAMP's Apache to accept SSL

By default, Apache is not configured to accept SSL connections, so we have to change that. Open `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and make sure the following lines are NOT commented out. If they are, remove the `#` at the beginning of the line:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so 

Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Also, look for this line:

```
Servername  localhost:443
```

and make sure the port is set to 443. 443 is the default port for HTTPS secured connections (regular, unsecured HTTP connections listen to port 80 by default).

Next, open `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` and make sure you have this line:

```
Listen 443
```

Again, this is important because we have to set up everything on the same port. To this end, you should also click on the MAMP icon in your MAC's dock, hit `Preferences`, go to the `Ports` tab and choose `Set Web & MySql ports to 80 & 3306`.

Stop and restart MAMP to apply the changes we've made so far.

### 3) Configure the default Virtual Host for SSL

While still in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`, look for these lines:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
```

These lines set Apache's default behavior for all HTTPS connections. The `ServerName` is just a dummy name that you should replace with `localhost`; you should also make sure that the default `DocumentRoot` does match with your projects root folder.

So change the above lines as follows:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/htdocs" 
ServerName localhost
```

As you scroll a bit further down, while we're still in the default `VirtualHost` directive, you will find these two lines:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
```

Change these to wherever you put the files we genereated in step 1. Like I said before, I've put mine in "/Applications/MAMP/ssl", so I've changed the 
above lines to:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/ssl/server.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/ssl/server.key"
```

Stop and restart MAMP to apply the changes. Now if you go to `https://localhost` you should be able to see the list of projects in your root folder. That's it for `localhost`!

### 4) Create a SSL certificate for custom local domains

What if you wanted to create a custom domain `myproject.dev` and use SSL for that too, so you could access it at `https://myproject.dev`?

Pretty much like what we did for `localhost`, we need to create a SSL certificate specifically for the `myproject.dev` domain, then configure a virtual host for `myproject.dev`. Let's start with creating the certificate.

Again, I've found [this little tool](https://github.com/christianalfoni/create-ssl-certificate) called `create-ssl-certificate` that will generate for you an SSL certificate for a specific local domain. This too is very easy to use, the only not so clear part is that it is a NPM package that you can install globally with `npm -g install create-ssl-certificate`.

If everything went well with `create-ssl-certificate`, you should now have two files, just like it was with `localhost` in step 1. By default, `create-ssl-certificate` calls the generated files `ssl.crt` and `ssl.key`. I've renamed them as `server.crt` and `server.key` to be consistent with the `localhost` files. Then I've created a `ssl` folder in the `myproject` root folder, and moved the files in there.

Let's forget about the files for a moment and proceed to some Apache configuration.

### 4) Configure MAMP's Apache to accept Virtual Hosts

**If you've created virtual hosts before, you have probably already done this, so you can skip this step.**

The only thing we need to do to 'activate' the possibility of creating virtual hosts is to go to `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and uncomment this line:

`Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

### 5) Configure your local domain's Virtual Host for SSL

Now we can set up a virtual host so that we can access `myproject` at `https://myproject.dev`. First of all, edit your `hosts` file and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1   myproject.dev
```

Then, go to `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and add the following:

```
<VirtualHost myproject.dev:443>
    ServerName myproject.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/myproject"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/myusername/Sites/myproject/ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/myusername/Sites/myproject/ssl/server.key"        
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration, you will be able to access `https://myproject.dev` because the server is instructed to search for the SSL certificates we've created in step 4.

Comment: Do not use `.DEV` as a fake local TLD, you will get into all sort of troubles as this is a real and live TLD, managed by Google. Either register a domain name and use it as suffix of all your names, or use the appropriate TLD sanctioned for documentation and hence local uses: `.EXAMPLE`, `.TEST`, `.INVALID`.

Comment: Relevant documentation for certificates: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: "To be able to use HTTPS with localhost we actually need two certificates" not strictly technically mandatory. You can use a self signed certificate. But of course you will need your browser to trust it.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you! Running MAMP 6.6 with Apache/2.4.46 I did not need to add the line `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so ` as that module is loaded by default.